# More efficient way to make unicode escape codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding

I am using python to automatically generate `qsf` files for Qualtrics online surveys. The `qsf` file requires unicode characters to be escaped using the `\u+hex` convention: 'слово' = '\u0441\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043e'. Currently, I am achieving this with the following expression:

```
'слово'.encode('ascii','backslashreplace').decode('ascii')
```

The output is exactly what I need, but since this is a two-step process, I wondered if there is a more efficient way to get the same result.

Comment: which python version?

Comment: @Ni. I am using python 3

Comment: If you find yourself doing this often, just write a very short function to do it for you. Don't worry about efficiency unless there's a compelling reason to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your output file as 'wb', then it accepts a byte stream rather than unicode arguments:

```
s = 'слово'
with open('data.txt','wb') as f:
    f.write(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
    f.write(b'\n')  # add a line feed
```

This seems to do what you want:

```
$ cat data.txt
\u0441\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043e
```

and it avoids both the decode as well as any translation that happens when writing unicode to a text stream.

---

Updated to use encode('unicode_escape') as per the suggestion of @J.F.Sebastian.

%timeit reports that it is quite a bit faster than encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace'):

```
In [18]: f = open('data.txt', 'wb')

In [19]: %timeit f.write(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
The slowest run took 224.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit f.write(s.encode('ascii','backslashreplace'))
The slowest run took 9.13 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.37 µs per loop

In [21]: f.close()
```

Curiously, the lag from timeit for encode('unicode_escape') is a lot longer than that from encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace') even though the per loop time is faster, so be sure to test both in your environment.

Comment: Just be warned that once you open the file as a byte stream, you can't write regular Unicode strings to it anymore (without encoding).

Comment: That's a good thing in this case. @bebob says that the file format requires unicode escapes, so any attempt to write to the file without specifying the escaped encoding will raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that it is a performance bottleneck in your application but `s.encode('unicode_escape')` can be faster than `s.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')`.

To avoid calling `.encode()` manually, you could pass the encoding to `open()`:

```
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='unicode_escape') as file:
    print(s, file=file)
```

Note: it translates non-printable ascii characters too e.g., a newline is written as `\n`, tab as `\t`, etc.

Comment: `print(s, file=file)` puts `\n` in the file rather than linefeed.