# How to convert actual Unicode to \u0123

Tags: bash, text, utf-8, sh, encode

I want to turn Unicode text into pure ASCII encoding using escape sequences.

Input :`Ɏɇ衳` outputs to ... `"\u024E\u0247\u8873"`

Basically the **opposite** of this.

```
$ echo -e "\u024E\u0247\u8873"
Ɏɇ衳
```

I want the encoding to stay in `utf8`, all I'm doing is changing forms.

#### I've Tried:

```
iconv -f utf8 -t utf8  $file
iconv -f utf8 -t utf16  $file
```

Comment: The `\u...` form is used to specify a character when you don't have a way to type the character directly, but you already have the characters, so why do you need this type of conversion?

Comment: Also, if that string is input of some kind, it's *already* encoded (probably with UTF-8), because bytes are the only way to pass data around in shell.

Comment: The reason I need the `\u...` is for operations on the `\u...`, you could pretty much change most characters by shifting some things around. I didn't exactly know what the `\u...` was, so thank you for the name.

Comment: For a Python solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258152/more-efficient-way-to-make-unicode-escape-codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mentioned codes `024E, 0247, ..` are called *Unicode code points* and are independent from UTF-8 or UTF-16.
If `perl` is your option, you can retrieve the codes with:

```
perl -C -ne 'map {printf "\\u%04X", ord} (/./g)' <<< "Ɏɇ衳"; echo
```

which outputs:

```
\u024E\u0247\u8873
```

**Explanation**

The perl code above is mostly equivalent to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;

$str = "Ɏɇ衳";
foreach $chr ($str =~ /./g) {
    printf "\\u%04X", ord($chr);
}
print "\n";
```

- `use utf8` specifies the string is encoded in UTF-8 (just because the string is embedded in the script).
- `($str =~ /./g)` brakes the string into an array of characters.
- `foreach` iterates over the array of characters.
- `ord` returns the *code point* of the given character.

**EDIT**

If you want to auto-scale the number of digits considering the out-of-BMP characters, try instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;

$str = "Ɏɇ衳";
foreach $chr ($str =~ /./g) {
    $n = ord($chr);
    $d = $n > 0xffff ? 8 : 4;
    printf "\\u%0${d}X", $n;
}
```

Comment: How does this behave for code points outside the BMP which cannot be encoded in four hex digits?

Comment: Good question ;-). The `ord()` function of Perl works well for the characters out of BMP. For instance `perl -C -ne 'map {printf "\\u%04X", ord} (/./g)' <<< ""` outputs `\u10300` as expected, thanks to the behavior of `printf()` in case the value exceeds the digits of length modifier.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what is expected. Python uses `\U00010300` for this character (uppercase `U` and eight hex digits). `\u1030` followed by `0` would be my interpretation of your output.

Comment: If we wanted to handle the code point in 32bit, then just use "%08X" instead of "%04X". It's our responsibilty, not Perl's.

Comment: You could make the script choose between these representations depending on whether the `ord()` is bigger than 65535.  I would imagine producing unambiguous output *is* the responsibility of this script, though the OP could be clearer on what exactly they need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Your explanation still says that you are applying the notation to Unicode codepoints whereas the discussion and final code do it the way the notation is used in programming languages: UTF-16 code units.

Answer (score -1):

If you have that in a file you can use iconv.

```
iconv -f $input_encoding -t $output_encoding $file
```

check "man iconv" for more details

Comment: I don't think you understand, `Ɏɇ衳` is my input, lets say I don't know what `"\u024E\u0247\u8873"` is. I want to input `Ɏɇ衳` and get `"\u024E\u0247\u8873"` as the output. I'm not looking to change `utf-8` to `utf-16 `or any of that sort.